# poslin() function in octave does not give the desired output

Tags: neural-network, octave

I have a little confusion about the poslin() function in octave . If I give in `poslin(-1)` , the output is the desired `0` ; and for `poslin(n)` , the output is `n` . However if I give in `poslin( [ 3 ; -1])` ; the result is not `[3 ; 0]` ; which is somewhat expected , since the input to the poslin() function is not a scalar , but a vector . Now , if so ; how is it possible to convert `[3 ; -1] to [3 ; 0]` using poslin() function . Any suggestion will be helpful .

Comment: the function `poslin()` is not part of Octave. Where did you obtain it? Are you doing the machine learning course from coursera? They distribute their own functions so only students will know what you're talking about.

Comment: I think I got my answer anyway . The poslin() do exist under neural network header ; which I downloaded from sourceforge . Any how , the answer is poslin() should be called for individual elements of a matrix ; not the whole matrix .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily define your own vectorized poslin, e.g. `poslin = @(x) x .* (x > 0)`